# Binary tree level order traversal time complexity

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

[HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/) it is explained that method 1 of level order traversal has a time complexity of O(n^2). Can someone please explain me this. I am not sure how author is saying that printGivenLevel() takes O(n).

"Time Complexity: O(n^2) in worst case. For a skewed tree, printGivenLevel() takes O(n) time where n is the number of nodes in the skewed tree. So time complexity of printLevelOrder() is O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + .. + O(1) which is O(n^2)."

On the contrary [HERE](http://leetcode.com/2010/09/binary-tree-level-order-traversal-using_17.html), it seems to be proved that it is O(n)

Comment: In the second one, it assumes the tree is balanced, the first doesn't make that assumption

Comment: But how worst case is O(n^2) .. can you please help me understand that.

Comment: @amit's answer explains that quite well.

Comment: @amit's answer explains that quite well. [2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the attached code, `printGivenLevel()` is `O(n)` indeed for worst case.
The *complexity function) of `printGivenLevel()` is:

```
T(n) = T(left) + T(right) + O(1)
where left = size of left subtree
      right = size of right subtree
```

In worst case, for each node in the tree there is at most one son, so it looks something like this:

```
                     1
                    2
                   3
                  4
                 5
                6
               7
              8       
            ...
```

Now, note that the way the algorithm works, you start from the root, and travel all the way to the required level, while decreasing the `level` variable every time you recurse. So, in order to get to the `n`th level, you are going to need at least `n` invokations of `printGivenLevel()`, so the *complexity function* of `printGivenLevel()` for the above example is:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(1) + O(1) = O(n) (can be proved used master theorem)
```

The first implementation requires you to do `printGivenLevel()` for each level, so for the same example, you get a worst case running time of `O(n^2)`, since you need `O(k)` to print each level from `1` to `k`, which is `O(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n) =(*) O(n(n+1)/2) = O(n^2)`, where the equality marked with `(*)` is from [sum or arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)

Comment: Which code are you referring to when you say "In the attached code"?

Comment: "in order to get to the nth level, you are going to need at least n invokations of printGivenLevel(), which makes it O(n)."  How is that ? Are you assuming printGivenLevel() to be O(1) ?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "The first implementation"

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I refer to the first implementation in the post you linked to, where the tree level order traversal is implemented using the `printGivenLevel()`.  Look at editted answer which tried to clarify the issue.

Comment: answer is still confusing. Are you suggesting first implementation is different from 'second' implementation.  Anyways never mind

Answer (score 0):

We can perform level order traversal in an easy way with always(best,avg,worst) O(n) Time complexity.

Simple Python code:

```
def level_order(self):
    print(self.root.data,end=' ')
    root=self.root
    a=[root]
    while len(a)!=0:
        tmp=[]
        for i in a:
            if i.left!=None:
                tmp.append(i.left)
                print(i.left.data,end=' ')
            if i.right!=None:
                tmp.append(i.right)
                print(i.right.data,end=' ')
        a=tmp
```

Explanation: `a` is a list of all addresses of nodes at current level; `tmp` is a list to store addresses of child nodes of `a`. If `len(a)=0`, that means it is the last level, so the loop breaks.